# Altbeacon not finding beacons on android 8+

Tags: android, kotlin, altbeacon, eddystone

I'm using Alt beacon in my project to detect beacons, it is working perfectly on my Samsung s7 (Android 7) but on a Samsung s10, Oneplus 6 and Google Pixel 3 XL (Android 9/10) it doesn't work at all.

The code just doesn't seem to find any beacons.

My code starts with a permission check:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(view, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Requesting Permission.")
    openPermissionDialog()
} else {
    startBeacon()
}
```

Then inside of my start beacon code bluetooth gets turned on and I create my beacon manager

```
val mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    if(mBluetoothAdapter != null){
         if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.enable()
         }

         Log.d(TAG, "Permissions accepted, bluetooth is on.")

         model.beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(view)
         BeaconController.startBeacon(model.beaconManager, view)
    }
```

Lastly inside of BeaconController I have a singleton companion object that will bind the beacon every 20 minutes. This is because when I find a beacon it will unbind.

```
class BeaconController {

    companion object {

        private val TAG = "HomePresenter"
        private var hasTimerStarted = false

        fun startBeacon(beaconManager: BeaconManager?, view: HomeActivityView) {

            if (!hasTimerStarted) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Timer starting")
                hasTimerStarted = true

                val handler = Handler()
                Thread(object : Runnable {
                    override fun run() {

                        if (beaconManager?.isBound(view) != null) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Beacon binding")
                            beaconManager.bind(view)
                            beaconManager.beaconParsers.clear()
                            beaconManager.beaconParsers.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT))
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Beacon is bound")
                        }

                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1200000) // 20 Minutes

                    }
                }).start()

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Timer already started.")
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Once the beacon is bound I run some logic in my onBeaconServiceConnect to send an analytic when I find a beacon

```
  override fun onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        model.beaconManager?.addRangeNotifier { beacons, _ ->
            if (beacons.isNotEmpty()) {
                val firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next()
                val firstBeaconNameSpace = "${firstBeacon.id1}".replace("0x", "")
                val firstBeaconIdentifier = "${firstBeacon.id2}".replace("0x", "")

                Log.d(TAG, "Beacon $firstBeaconNameSpace - $firstBeaconIdentifier is " + firstBeacon.distance + " meters away.")

            }
        }

        /**
         * Attach
         */

        try {
            model.beaconManager?.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(Region("com.MYAPP.MYAPP", null, null, null))
            Log.d(TAG, "Added Range Notifier")
        } catch (e: RemoteException) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error adding Range Notifier")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this wasn't working is because I was binding the beacon before actually adding the Beacon layout...

Before:

```
beaconManager?.bind(view)
beaconManager?.beaconParsers?.clear()
beaconManager?.beaconParsers?.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT))
```

After:

```
beaconManager?.beaconParsers?.clear()
beaconManager?.beaconParsers?.add(BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT))
beaconManager?.bind(view)
```

Comment: Glad to hear you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably has nothing to do with the Android Beacon Library and is simply related to the Android operating system's restrictions on using timers on Android 8+.

Starting with version 8, Android apps are terminated by the operating system after 10 minutes of background execution unless a ForegroundService is active.  This timer will therefore NEVER fire unless you keep the screen on, unlocked, and the app visible on the screen: `handler.postDelayed(this, 1200000) // 20 Minutes`

You can change your architecture to get this to work on Android 8+, or you can configure the library to use it's built-in ForegroundService to get around the restriction.  See [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html) for instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The use case for my app is only in the foreground, I don't need to listen in the background. Even if I leave the app open on the screen where the beacon binds, it doesn't find a beacon ever. Where as the android 7 device finds it after around 20 seconds (as expected)

Comment: Are you sure about this?  It would take quite a bit of effort to leave a screen on for 20 minutes straight without ever letting the screen turn off or the phone lock.  You also mention "20 seconds" in the comment above, but the code clearly says "20 **minutes**".

Comment: Yes its inside of a handler, this means the code will run once instantly, and then again within 20 minutes. It will then bind to the consumer. Then the phone will find a beacons (within roughly 20 seconds). Once it finds a beacon, the consumer will unbind.

Comment: The code inside of the thread will run, then handler will then delay for the 1200000 milliseconds, and run that code again.

Answer (score 0):

I know, because I had problems when I worked with Beacons, that for devices running Oreo and above the background task doesn't work.

For that devices I used JobScheduler....

That's a tutorial about it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EQWmME-hNA

I hope that can help you out ;)

Good luck